# Creating PDF with wkhtmltopdf on linux server

Tags: pdf, linux

I've created a Wordpress site that runs on a WAMP server as well as a Linux server hosted by GoDaddy.

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate the PDF documents.

On the WAMP server everything works as expected, but on the Godaddy+Linux server no PDF is created and I simply get an empty document.

I checked the logs and there is nothing being listed.

Am I doing something wrong in the code for the linux environment, or something wrong on the server due to the host?

```
<?php

require_once("../../../../wp-blog-header.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['url']) && !empty($_GET['url'])) {
    $post_id = url_to_postid($_GET['url']);
    $post = $post_id ? get_post($post_id) : null;

    if($post){
        $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);
        $html = file_get_contents($post_url);

        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array('pipe', 'r'), // stdin
            1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
            2 => array('pipe', 'a'), // stderr  <http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#97012>
        );
        $exe_path = (PHP_OS == 'WINNT') ? '"C:/wamp/bin/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe"' : ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/cgi-bin/whkhtmltopdf");

        //$process = proc_open("$exe_path -q - -", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
        $process = proc_open("$exe_path -q --print-media-type - -", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

        // Send the HTML on stdin
        fwrite($pipes[0], $html);
        fclose($pipes[0]);

        //stream_set_timeout($pipes[1], 1);
        //stream_set_timeout($pipes[2], 1);

        // Read the outputs
        $pdf = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        $errors = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

        // Close the process
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        $return_value = proc_close($process);

        if($errors) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            header('Content-Type: text/plain');
            echo "An error occurred during PDF generation:\r\n\r\n$errors";
        } else {
            $file_name = "$post->post_title.pdf";

            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
            header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($pdf));
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file_name . '";');
            echo $pdf;
        }
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        echo "An error occurred during PDF generation:\r\n\r\nUnrecognized post.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was two-fold here for me. I was able to determine that I was using the wrong executable version (32bit vs 64bit). There was a segfault error code from the command line, which after being fixed lead me to another issue which was the lack of a number of libraries on the server.